# Displaying text at 45 degree in Text View, with a custom background.

Tags: android, android-canvas, textview

I have a textView in a list on which I want to display text at 45 degrees slant and with center horizontal + center vertical properties. SO far:

My custom TextView Class:

```
   public class AngledTextView extends TextView  {  
    public AngledTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {  
        super(context, attrs);  

    }  

    @Override  
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
        canvas.save();  
        canvas.rotate(45, this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2);  
        super.onDraw(canvas);  
        canvas.restore();  
    }  
}
```

XML Code:

```
<com.example.AngledTextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewx"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeSecondary"
        android:background="@drawable/image_sticker" />
```

In the class:

```
final AngledTextView tv_red = (AngledTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewx);
            tv_red.setText("Today");
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Desired:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I tried to make the same in my project. I used `android:rotation`, `android:translationX` and `android:translationY` properties for this. I added `android:paddingStart` and `android:paddingEnd` to fix bug when the text is out of the screen. After some experiments with size, translations and paddings I used this code for short two lines text:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewStatus"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="31dp"
            android:paddingStart="31dp"
            android:rotation="45"
            android:text="@string/empty"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:translationX="65dp"
            android:translationY="-65dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set:

```
android:rotation="45"
android:background="@drawable/your_drawable"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this property to your custom TextView

```
android:rotationX = "45"
```

else this in your java code

```
yourcustomview.setRotation(45);
```